# Service activation in OSGI results in Time out

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

Using a blueprint.xml, I am trying to create a jndi service for datasource and having a reference in the same bundle.The datasource service is not activated and the reference fails after certain time and results in time out.
Also, when the reference of service is commented in the blueprint, the service gets activated. 
Is there a way I can handle the activation of the service with its reference also present in the same bundle.

```
<service id="zDS" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="zOltpDataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/zDS"/>
    </service-properties>  
</service>
<bean id="zDao"
    class="com.h.h.common.dao.ZDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean> 
<reference id="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"
             filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/zDS)">
</reference>  

   <bean id="zOltpDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${z.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${z.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${z.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${z.password}"/>      
    <property name="initialSize" value="${z.initialSize}"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${z.maxIdle}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="${z.maxActive}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${z.validationQuery}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${z.testOnBorrow}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: You have skipped the important part of the Blueprint XML: where is the bean `zOltpDataSource` defined?

Comment: The zOltpDataSource  as in bluprint is added to the code section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Blueprint container will not initialise until all of its mandatory dependencies are satisfied: see [Initialization of a Blueprint Container](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.blueprint.html#i2272468) from the Blueprint Specification.

Therefore you cannot use a `<reference>` to a service that is only published from the same container, because there is effectively a circular dependency. Of course your container will start if there is a matching `DataSource` service from another bundle.

You shouldn't need to refer to the service, however. Just inject the `zOltpDataSource` bean directly into the `zDao` bean as follows:

```xml
<bean id="zDao"
    class="com.h.h.common.dao.ZDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="zOltpDataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Neil for the detailed explanation. My idea of putting datasource as a service was to use the datasource in other bundles too.I can either move the datasource in a new bundle to expose the service now or else declare the service in this bundle for other bundles and just inject the datasource in this bundle.

Comment: You can export the data source as a service and still inject the data source bean directly like suggested by Neil. So your bundle will start up and still other bundles can also use the data source via the service.

Comment: Thanks Christian Schneider . I understand that would work as the circular dependency is removed if we inject the datasource directly and export as service for the other bundles.I took a different approach since we are in microservice environment and created a light weight bundle just for the exporting the datasource as service. All bundles now expects this datasource bundle installed as mentioned in feature.xml and use the reference of this service to inject the datasource.